# PHP Regex: Difference between \s and \\s

Tags: php, regex

I understand \s is used to match white space character, but sometimes I see 
 "\\s" is used in preg match and working fine. For eg:

```
if (preg_match("/\\s/", $myString)) {
   // there are spaces
}

if (preg_match("/\s/", $myString)) {
   // there are spaces
}
```

Is there any difference between above two code blocks?

Comment: @Tushar: If "\s" => regex s, then why preg_match("/\s/", "hello hi") = 1 ?

Comment: @joHN: the output is correct for `("/\s/", "hello hi") = 1` as there is only one whitespace. the first expression will try to match `\s` in the string..try here https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Tushar: try var_dump(preg_match("/\\s/","\shello",$matches));

Comment: @Tushar: could please provide an example string where above code block will have different results?

Comment: Dont try this on any online site..try it on your local compiler..i got what OP is asking after i tried it in my python console

Comment: In python there is something like `r"\\s"` which can be used to show the difference in result..dont know about PHP though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to make sense of the text from the manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

> Single and double quoted PHP strings have special meaning of
>   backslash.
>       Thus if \ has to be matched with a regular expression \\, then "\\\\" 
>       or '\\\\' must be used in PHP code.

I might not be correct but here I go.

When you use something like

```
preg_match("/\\s/", $myString)
```

What it is doing is converting \\ to \, which in turns make the string to be \s thus it behaves normally i.e its meaning doesn't change and the created regex is '/\s/' internally which matches "spaces"

To match \s in a string you would have to do something as follows

```
preg_match("/\\\\s/", $myString)
```

So the answer is \s or \\s in the regex string doesn't make any difference, personally I think using \s is simpler and easy to understand.

Comment: Even I use single quotes to specify the pattern, I didnt see any difference. I didnt meant to match "\s", but to match space. So there is no difference in using \s and \\s (double or single quotes)?

Comment: @joHN that is what the manual is saying, it doesn't matter regarding double or single quotes, a backslash has a special meaning for the PHP string, it escapes all non-alpha characters. backslash itself being a non-alpha gets converted to backslash, and when the compiler see a "\" followed by "s" it tries to match spaces

Comment: The real reason why both patterns work is that PHP keeps the backslash in uknown escape sequences. With unknown escape sequences the behavior is undefined, and PHP authors (and Python's) decided to keep backslashes while in JavaScript these single backslashes are omitted in C strings.  It is best to use double backslashes in double quoted patterns to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Pardon my ignorance, but I don't think I fully understand when you say " while in JavaScript these single backslashes are omitted in C strings. It is best to use double backslashes in double quoted patterns to avoid ambiguity". 1. What are C strings? 
2. What kind of ambiguity are we trying to prevent? as for PHP both single and double quotes would work the same in a regex?. If you can provide references or an example that would be great!

Comment: C strings are those that can contain escape sequences (`\n` denoting LF, etc). You cannot declare them in literal (verbatim string literals, terminology can be different) strings. It is true that even `\b` is  still a word boundary in double and single quoted string literal in PHP, I tested that myself and was rather surprised. Note that in JS , Java, Python, `\b` in a regular string literal is a backspace character. Ambiguity is thus in PHP is resolved by the engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
\s  - to match all white spaces

\\s - to match all white spaces

\\\s - to match all \s
```

Comment: I didnt get it, could you show me an example string where both pattern will return different results?

Comment: Please try in your local system, online tools does not correctly show the uniqueness. It does not have any difference I think.

Comment: After the edit, the results are correct. No difference between \s and \\s expression.

Comment: Yes, I only checked in online tool. sorry